# Append in python with split

Tags: python

What's wrong with this code?

It displays the following error:

> EOFError : EOF when reading a line

```
n,K = map(int,input().split())

arr = []

count = 0

for i in range(0,n):

   arr.append(input().split())

print(arr)
```

Comment: please post complete error stack

Comment: I don't get the error when I test your script, what did you do to get this error? As @Akshay Nevrekar said, can you post the entire error message?
Note : you shoud add some `print('something')` before your `input()` to allow the user know what he has to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to use raw_input instead of input.
Values passed in input are converted in python expressions. Your first input for example '3 5' will be converted to expression ('', 1, 3, '3 5') which is not what you want.

This is only issue with python2. In python3 input and raw_input behave same.

Comment: If I type `x = input()` and then `1 2`, `x` is a string with the value `'1 2'`. Moreover, `x.split()` yields `['1', '2']`. The format seems correct for what @VijayaKrishnan wants. Does the result of `input` vary between python2 and python3 (I used python 3.5 for this test)?

Comment: yes it is issue with python2. You won't get this error in python 3.5

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do. Check if this helps:

```
n = input(": ").split()

arr = []

count = len(n)


for word in n:

    arr.append(word)

print(arr)

print("*"*15)

print("You have "+str(count)+" words.")
```

split() is going to split the provided input string by space (as a delimiter). Each piece of the string is now called a **word**. Each **word** is appended to your **arr** list.